# Setting width and height for MV4 login-dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Where do I set the width and height of (and other adjustments) for the login-form in MVC4?
I am creating a web app that works fairly well on the mobile without any additional changes, but I need to adjust the login-form. 
I've looked in the css, the jqueryui. dialog, as well as the cshtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `_LoginPartial.cshtml` add another attribute for the login and registration `ActionLink`.

For example, set the width to `400`, and add this attribute to the link: `data_dialog_width = "400"`

Result:

```
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink", data_dialog_title = "Registration", data_dialog_width = "400" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", data_dialog_title = "Identification", data_dialog_width = "400" })</li>
```

Comment: You can also go in into AjaxLogin.js and edit this line width: link.data('dialog-width') || 600,